# Input to reshape is a tensor with 4816896 values, but the requested shape has 7168

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to implement a Capsule Network model with custom input shapes. The code for the model is shown below. I have 2 classes in my dataset. Here are the parameters:

```
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)  # Example input shape
num_capsules = 2
capsule_dim = 32
num_routing = 3
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

class CapsuleLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_capsules, capsule_dim, num_routing=3):
        super(CapsuleLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_capsules = num_capsules
        self.capsule_dim = capsule_dim
        self.num_routing = num_routing

    def build(self, input_shape):
        input_dim = input_shape[-1]
        self.W = self.add_weight(shape=[1, 1, input_dim, self.num_capsules * self.capsule_dim],
                                 initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                 trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        print(inputs.shape)
        batch_size = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
        input_num_capsules = inputs.shape[1]
        input_dim = inputs.shape[2]

        # Reshape inputs to [batch_size, input_num_capsules, 1, input_dim]
        inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [batch_size, input_num_capsules, 1, input_dim])

        # Tile the weights for each input capsule
        W_tiled = tf.tile(self.W, [batch_size, input_num_capsules, 1, 1])

        # Perform element-wise multiplication between inputs and W
        inputs_hat = inputs * W_tiled

        # Reshape inputs_hat to [batch_size, input_num_capsules, num_capsules, capsule_dim]
        inputs_hat = tf.reshape(inputs_hat, [batch_size, input_num_capsules, self.num_capsules, self.capsule_dim])

        # Initialize the routing logits to zeros
        b = tf.zeros(shape=[batch_size, input_num_capsules, self.num_capsules])

        # Iterative routing by agreement
        for i in range(self.num_routing):
            c = tf.nn.softmax(b, axis=2)
            outputs = squash(tf.reduce_sum(c[:, :, :, None] * inputs_hat, axis=1, keepdims=True))

            if i < self.num_routing - 1:
                b += tf.reduce_sum(outputs * inputs_hat, axis=-1)

        return tf.squeeze(outputs, axis=1)

def squash(x):
    squared_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(x), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    scale = squared_norm / (1 + squared_norm)
    return scale * x / tf.sqrt(squared_norm + tf.keras.backend.epsilon())

# Usage example
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)  # Example input shape
num_capsules = 2
capsule_dim = 32
num_routing = 3
input_data = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
capsule_layer = CapsuleLayer(num_capsules, capsule_dim, num_routing)
output = capsule_layer(input_data)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

The model summary indicates that the total trainable parameters are 192. However, when I try to fit the model using the `model.fit` function with my training data, I encounter an error: "Input to reshape is a tensor with 4816896 values, but the requested shape has 7168." I'm not sure how to resolve this error, and I've checked similar posts, but I couldn't find a solution. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you in advance!